# Xcode 10 Beta Media Shortcut

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10, ios12

Does anyone know the shortcut for Xcode 10 beta to reach the media part?
I already searched at google but I'm not able to find it. May its possible to get the old view if anyone knows what I mean?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Shortcut to open the Media Library Tab:

<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

At this point the official documentation does not cover some use cases at Xcode 10 beta so I'm not able to find a way to move the media part to the old position.